# Replace series with restrictions

Tags: replacement, variable-definitions

I am trying to implement a code where I have the following problem:
Consider I have the following series, which I can express as follows:
$$ \sum_{j<k} x_j^4 x_k^4 = \frac{(\sum_j x_j^4)^2 - \sum_jx_j^8}{2}$$

I want to express it in such a way because I have the values for $\sum_j x_j^4$ and $\sum_j x_j^8$.

Of course, I have similar cases like:
$$\sum_{j<k} (x_j^2x_k^6+x_j^6x_k^2)=\left(\sum_j x_j^2\right)\left(\sum_k x_k^6\right)-\sum_j x_j^8$$

How can I tell Mathematica to perform this replacements?

Comment: Your second example is not true.

Comment: I believe it is true now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to rewrite a generic symmetric polynomial in terms of [power sum polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_sum_symmetric_polynomial). The definition of a power sum polynomial is:

$$p_n = \sum _i x_i^n$$

To do this, I will use the function [`SymmetricReduction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SymmetricReduction), which works with elementary symmetric polynomials, whose definition is:

$$e_n = \sum _{i_1, i_2, ..., i_n} x_{i_1} x_{i_2} ... x_{i_n}$$

Now, one can define the [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) in terms of the power sum polynomials using the [Newton-Girard formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities):

```
e[0] = 1;
e[n_] := Expand[Sum[p[n-k] e[k](-1)^(k+n+1), {k, 0, n-1}]]/n
```

For example:

```
e[3]
```

> 1/3 (p[1]^3/2 - 3/2 p[1] p[2] + p[3])

We can now use [`SymmetricReduction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SymmetricReduction). [`SymmetricReduction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SymmetricReduction) needs to use explicit polynomials, that is, the dimensions of the indices have to be specified. I will use a dimension of 4 for your sums. Then, the first example, rewritten using $z_i = x_i^4$

```
SymmetricReduction[
    Sum[z[i] z[j], {i, 4}, {j, i-1}],
    Array[z, 4],
    Array[e, 4]
] //First //Simplify
```

> 1/2 (p[1]^2 - p[2])

Since the power sum polynomial `p[1]` is $\sum _i x_i^4$ and `p[2]` is $\sum _i x_i^8$, this agrees with the desired result.

The second example, rewritten using $z_i = x_i^2$:

```
SymmetricReduction[
    Sum[z[i] z[j]^3 + z[j] z[i]^3,{i,4}, {j,i-1}],
    Array[z, 4],
    Array[e, 4]
] //First //Simplify
```

> p[1] p[3] - p[4]

In this case we have `p[1]` being equivalent to $\sum _i x_i^2$, `p[3]` being equivalent to $\sum _i x_i^6$ and `p[4]` being equivalent to $\sum _i x_i^8$, reproducing the desired result.

Comment: What do you mean by "dimensions of the indices"?

Comment: @AlonsoPerezLona What is the maximum value of the indices $j$ and $k$?

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you.